# How to use two arrays in one foreach loop using C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I loop through two arays using a `foreach` loop?
I found this previously, but that's for PHP not c#

```
$images = array('image1', 'image2', ...);
$descriptions = array('description1', 'description2', ...);

foreach (array_combine($images, $descriptions) as $image => $desc) {
  echo $image, $desc;
}
```

my thought is to have something like the following

```
string[] ValueA = {1,2,3}
string[] ValueB = (a,b,c}

foreach(something here from ValueA && ValueB)
{
   methodNameHere(ValueA, ValueB); //method I am calling requires the two values
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a for loop or a while loop ?

Comment: You can't do that in c#. What exactly do you try to accomplish?

Comment: if each array is going to be the same size you can just use a for loop and get each index at the same spot and call the method that way?

Comment: Oh well, the closest you can get to PHP is using dictionaries, but I don't see how far you can go, a for loop with a flag can be absolutely enough.

Comment: basically I wanted to combine to sets of data , I can do this manually but I think it will be much better if done with an array so that it walks through each set of data

Comment: Use: var mergedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList(); This will combine your two lists to one, without duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

            var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

            foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            // This code produces the following output: 

            // 1 one 
            // 2 two 
            // 3 three
```

Answer (score 2):

You will be Zip operation that come in .Net 4 in feature.  This on [link1](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx) and [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx) is description.

You will be right something like:

```
var alpha = new [] { A, B, C, D };
var day = new [] { "s", "s", "m", "t" };

var  alphasAndDays =  alpha.Zip(day, (n, w) => new { Alpha = n, Day = w });
foreach(var ad in  alphasAndDays)
{
   Console.WriteLine(aw.Alpha + aw.Day);
}
```

Comment: gave it go didnt get expected results, please note inside foreach I am running   methodNameHere(ValueA, ValueB) not concatenating the two

Answer (score 0):

A simple reiteration can do that:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] setA = new string[3] {"1", "2", "3"};
        string[] setB = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };

        foreach (string val1 in setA) {

            foreach (string val2 in setB) {

                Program test = new Program();
                String printer = test.concatString(val1, val2);

                Console.WriteLine(printer);

            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public string concatString(string value1, string value2) {

         String value3 = value1 + value2;
         return value3;
    }
}
```