# foreach loop with 2 hashset variables c#

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, hashset

I have the following

```
variableAs = "A12,B12,C12"
variableBs = "1.54,75.30,55.50"

method (HashSet<string> variableAs, HashSet<double> variableBs)

 foreach (var variableA in variableAs)

{
Method here requires the two values, must have preserved datatype
and be in same order, ie  A12 with 1.54, B12 with 75.30
}
```

I have tried zip from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054312/how-to-use-two-arrays-in-one-foreach-loop-using-c-sharp) but I do not know how it works with hashset arrays,
NOTE the Method i am editing has it has hashset,  the actual values are for example only, if there is an error, It must be my understanding of what a hashset is but I cannot change the hashset

Comment: first off you need to populate your input-string to a hashset. `"A12,B12,C12"` certainly is not a `HashSet`. You may use `String.Split(',')`, which at least gives you an array of strings.

Comment: A HashSet does not define an order

Comment: "if there is an error, It must be my understanding of what a hashset is" - sounds like it, if you're treating it as an *ordered* collection. But converting this into an actual [mcve] rather than pseudo-code would at least help to clarify which data types you're *actually* using.

Comment: well, if the function you need to implement really has two hashset-params, the requirement of joining two elements based on their index in those sets is non-sense, as there simply is no order in a hashset and thus no index. So either is the requirement non-sense or the function signature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first populate your input-strings into some collection:

```
var As = variableAs.Split(',');
var Bs = variableBs.Split(',');
```

However a `HashSet` is not an ordered collection and thus the wrong choice here. You'd need a `List` or just an array.

Now you may use the mentioned `Zip`-function to combine the two elements together:

```
var result = As.Zip(Bs, (a, b) => new { a, b });
```

See the complete code at this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9qTG2E

Comment: the Method i am editing has it has hashset,  the actual values are for example only, if there is an error, It must be my understanding of what a hashset is but I cannot change the hashset

Comment: What's the reason for preferring `(a, b) => new { a, b }` over `(a, b) => (a, b)`? Aren't [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) more convenient and efficient than [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#instantiation-of-anonymous-types)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you can of course also use a tuple, but that's pretty opinion-based.

Comment: @SamAsh but a hashset simply has no order, so there's no way to indicate which element is the first one and which is the second one.

Comment: According to the article [Choosing between anonymous and tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/choosing-between-anonymous-and-tuple#conclusion), the only compelling reason to prefer anonymous types over value-tuples is that the former have expression tree support.